# How to debug nHibernate/RhinoMocks TypeInitializer exception

Tags: nhibernate

Pulling my hair out trying to debug this one.  Earlier this morning, this code was working fine, and I can't see what I've changed to break it.  Now, whenever I try to open an nHibernate session, I'm getting the following error:

Test method BCMS.Tests.Repositories.BlogBlogRepositoryTests.can_get_recent_blog_posts threw exception:  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Environment' threw an exception. --->  System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Castle.DynamicProxy.Serialization.ProxyObjectReference,Rhino.Mocks, Version=3.5.0.1337, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b3305902db7183f'..

Any thoughts on how to debug what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue as you - in my case it was with NLog's static method:

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
```

I'd replaced the current thread's principal with a Rhinomocks stub:

```
var identity = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IIdentity>();
identity.Stub(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Return(true);
var principal = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IPrincipal>();
principal.Stub(x => x.Identity).Return(identity);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Running unit tests for my code threw the same exception from the original question.

The stack trace:

```
at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
at System.AppDomain.get_EvidenceNoDemand()
at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.get_AppConfig()
at NLog.LogFactory.get_Configuration()
at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey cacheKey)
at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(String name)
at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
at MyClassHere...
```

So as you can see from the stack trace an attempt to read the config file is made, which won't work - why?  Because the now mocked current principal is no longer the WindowsPrincipal that we had originally - it's now a mocked principal which won't have any sort of windows file access.

Thinking off the cuff here's a couple of ways to fix this issue.

1. Inject the logger into my class so that it can be stubbed (I probably should be doing this anyway I suppose..).  This would allow me to use a stub for the Thread principal.
2. Modify the existing WindowsPrincipal (or create another based on it) on the thread to add in the roles required to call my methods.

-- UPDATE --

To fix my issue, in the end I decided to run with my first suggestion above.  To avoid writing my own abstraction of the NLog Logger I just leveraged what was offered from Common.Logging.  Class constructors now accept an ILog as one of their parameters, and the Unity config to inject the logger just looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ILog>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(x => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()));
```

Meanwhile, my unit tests now allow me to pass in a mocked logger.

```
var logger = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILog>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Some more info... it seems to be related to switching the Thread.CurrentPrincipal to a mocked IPrincipal implementation.  I do all my security checks in my domain model inside the entities.  The entity's methods check Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole() before modifying properties on the entity.

So, in order to test the entity's methods, I have to set different users (contributor user, moderator user, etc.) before I make my entity method calls.

I haven't figured out why this was working fine yesterday.

Here's an example of my Mocked IPrincipal:

```
        private static IPrincipal _blogContributorUser = null;
    public static IPrincipal BlogContributorUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _blogContributorUser)
            {
                var identity = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IIdentity>(); 
                identity.Stub(p => p.Name).Return("BlogContributor").Repeat.Any(); 
                var principal = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IPrincipal>(); 
                principal.Stub(p => p.Identity).Return(identity).Repeat.Any();
                principal.Stub(p => p.IsInRole(UserRoles.BlogContributor)).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
                principal.Stub(p => p.IsInRole(UserRoles.CommentContributor)).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
                principal.Stub(p => p.IsInRole(UserRoles.TagContributor)).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
                _blogContributorUser = principal;
            }
            return _blogContributorUser;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors like this usually indicate versioning issues.

What I suspect may be happening is that both RhinoMocks and NHibernate are making use of Castle.DynamicProxy type, but they are asking for different versions of that type.

Did you recently uprade RhinoMocks or NHibernate to a newer version?

If this isn't the issue, then more information would be helpful - do all tests fail, or just this particular one?

*edit* You may also wish to try adding these lines to your Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Rhino.Mocks")] 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Castle.DynamicProxy")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It looks like that it has trouble reading the config file, since CurrentPrincipal is changed. I have moved all that has to be initialized from the config file, before replacing the CurrentPrincipal (for example, opened NHibernate session, initialized Unity and that kind of stuff), and everything works after that. Of course, this is not a solution, just a workaround figured out by a desperate man.

Answer (score 1):

In case the error is related to mocking `IPrincipal` and/or `IIdentity` with RhinoMocks or Moq the solution is actually quite simple: don't use those frameworks but create simple fake types instead.

Here is an example for a simple "allow everything" implementation:

```
public class FakeIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string Name { get { return "IntegrationTest"; } }

    public string AuthenticationType { get { return "Kerberos"; } }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get { return true; } }
}

public class FakePrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public FakePrincipal() { this.Identity = new FakeIdentity(); }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) { return true; }
}
```

If you need more complexity take a look at the [`System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) class.